I implemented a MLP Neural Network in C++, but if i normally compile it doesn't work, if i use the debugger with VS Code it works
I tried to implemt a MLP Neural Network for digit recognition using Eigen3, but if i normally compile and execute it at some point all the parameters (weights, biases, activations) become NaN. Instead if i debug it with VS Code it works.
This is the network
#include "..\Headers\Network.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector;
using std::string;
using Eigen::VectorXd;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;

double sigmoide (double x);
double sigmoide_derivative(double x);
VectorXd sigmoide_derivative(VectorXd vec);
void load_val (string pi, VectorXd& pixels);
std::ofstream _log ("log.txt");

template <typename T>
void print(T& mat)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < mat.rows(); r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < mat.cols(); c++)
        {
        }
    }
}

Network::Network(vector<string> _data, int _l_rate, vector<int> dim) : data{_data}, l_rate{_l_rate}
{
    layers = dim.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < layers - 1; i++)
    {
        MatrixXd m = MatrixXd::Random(dim[i + 1], dim[i]);
        weights.push_back(m);
        VectorXd b = VectorXd::Random(dim[i + 1]);
        biases.push_back(b);
        VectorXd _z (dim[i + 1]);
        z.push_back(_z);
        VectorXd n (dim[i]);
        neurons.push_back(n);
    }
    VectorXd n_f (dim[layers - 1]);
    neurons.push_back(n_f);
}

void Network::learn(int epoch, int mini_batch)
{

    for(int e = 0; e < epoch; e++)
    {
        std::cout << "Epoch: " << e + 1 << "\n\n";
        double e_cost = 0;
        shuffle(begin(data), end(data), rng);
        for(unsigned long long int n = 0; n < data.size();)
        {
            e_cost += SGD(mini_batch, n);
        }
    }
}


double Network::SGD (int mini_batch, unsigned long long int& n_data)
{
    vector<VectorXd> p_d_biases = vector<VectorXd>();
    vector<MatrixXd> p_d_weights = vector<MatrixXd>();
    double b_cost = 0;
    for(int m = 0; m < mini_batch && n_data != data.size(); m++, n_data++)
    {
        feed_forward(data.at(n_data));
        SGD_b(p_d_biases, data.at(n_data));
        SGD_w(p_d_weights, p_d_biases);
        b_cost += cost(data.at(n_data));
    }
    step(p_d_weights, p_d_biases, mini_batch);
    return b_cost / mini_batch;
}

double Network::cost(string sample)
{
    VectorXd e_values = VectorXd();
    exp_values(sample, e_values);
    double s_cost = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < neurons[layers - 1].size(); i++)
    {
        if(e_values[i] == 1)
        {
            s_cost += std::pow(neurons.at(layers - 1)(i) - 1, 2);
        }
        else
        {
            s_cost += std::pow(neurons.at(layers - 1)(i), 2);
        }
    }
    return s_cost;
}

void Network::step(const vector<MatrixXd>& p_d_weights, const vector<VectorXd>& p_d_biases, int mini_batch)
{
    for(int l = layers - 2, n = 0; l >= 0; l--, n++)
    {
        VectorXd b_tmp (biases.at(l).rows());
        MatrixXd w_tmp (weights.at(l).rows(), weights.at(l).cols());
        for(int i = 0; i < layers - 1; i++)
        {
            b_tmp += p_d_biases.at((i * (layers - 1)) + n);
            w_tmp += p_d_weights.at((i * (layers - 1)) + n);
        }
        biases.at(l) -= l_rate * (b_tmp / mini_batch);
        weights.at(l) -= l_rate * (w_tmp / mini_batch);
    }
}

void Network::SGD_w (vector<MatrixXd>& p_d_weights, const vector<VectorXd>& p_d_biases)
{
    for(int l = layers - 2; l >= 0; l--)
    {
        p_d_weights.push_back(p_d_biases.at(p_d_biases.size() - (l + 1)) * neurons.at(l).transpose());
    }
}

void Network::SGD_b (vector<VectorXd>& p_d_biases, string sample)
{
    VectorXd e_values = VectorXd();
    exp_values(sample, e_values);
    for(int l = layers - 1; l > 0; l--)
    {
        if(l == (layers - 1))
        {
            p_d_biases.push_back((2*(neurons.at(l) - e_values)).cwiseProduct(sigmoide_derivative(z.at(l-1))));
        }
        else
        {
            VectorXd b =(weights.at(l).transpose() * p_d_biases.at(p_d_biases.size() - 1)).cwiseProduct(sigmoide_derivative(z.at(l - 1)));
            p_d_biases.push_back(b);
        }
    }
}

void Network::feed_forward(string sample)
{
    load_val(sample, neurons[0]);
    for(int l = 0; l < layers - 1; l++)
    {
        z.at(l) = weights.at(l) * neurons.at(l) + biases.at(l);
        for (int i = 0; i < biases.at(l).size(); i++)
        {
            neurons.at(l + 1)(i) = sigmoide(z.at(l)(i));
        }
    }
}

void Network::exp_values (string sample, VectorXd& e_values)
{
    e_values.resize(neurons[layers - 1].size());
    short digit = std::stoi(string(sample.begin(), sample.begin() + 1));
    for(int i = 0;  i < e_values.size(); i++)
    {
        if(i - digit == 0)
        {
            e_values(i) = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            e_values(i) = 0;
        }
    }
}

void load_val (string pi, VectorXd& pixels)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(auto s = pi.begin() + 3, p = pi.begin() + 1; s != pi.end(); s++)
    {
        if(*s == ',')
        {
            double t = std::stoi(std::string(p + 1, s)) / 255.;
            pixels(i) = t;
            p = s;
            i++;
        }
        if(s == (pi.end() - 1))
        {
            double t = std::stoi(std::string(s, pi.end())) / 255.;
            pixels(i) = t;
        }
    }
}

VectorXd sigmoide_derivative(VectorXd vec)
{
    VectorXd result = VectorXd();
    result.resize(vec.size());
    for(int r = 0; r < vec.rows(); r++)
    {
        result(r) = sigmoide_derivative(vec(r));
    }
    return result;
}

double sigmoide_derivative(double x)
{
    return std::exp(x) / std::pow(1 + std::exp(x), 2);
}

double sigmoide (double x)
{
    return 1. / (1 + (1. / std::exp(x)));
}



This is the main
int main()
{
    ifstream f_data ("..\\csv_files\\mnist_train.csv");
    vector<string> data;
    if(f_data.good())
    {
        while(!(f_data.eof())) 
        {
            string tmp;
            f_data >> tmp;
            data.push_back(tmp);
        }
        vector<int> dim {784, 16, 10};
        Network n (data, 3, dim);
        n.learn(20, 10);
    
        ifstream t_data ("..\\csv_files\\mnist_test.csv");
        string s;
        t_data >> s;
        cout << string(s.begin(), s.begin() + 1) << endl;
        n.feed_forward(s);
        print(n.getNeurons(2));
    }
    return 0;
}

I tried to disable the compiler optimizations, i controlled that everything was initiliazed, but other than this i don't know where to put my hands. I use as a compiler GCC from MinGW.

The thing is if you get different results with different compilers and/or debug/release you have undefined behavior somewhere.  This is also suspicious : while(!(f_data.eof())) (lookup why you shouldn't check eof in C++).  You are also unecessarily copying data instead of passing it by reference. Can it be you actually don't have a lot experience with C++, and just are trying to make things "work"?

std::isnan can tell you if a double is NaN. Test all your weights and biases for nan-ness in step, then trace back through the function to see where it is coming from.

@PepijnKramer Yes, i'm not very experienced, i wrote this program as an exercise to improve in the language and learn something more about neural network. Thanks for the advices, do you have any idea where the undefiend behavior could be?

@Botje i tried, but it's very strange because nan appears in a different moment and location every time i compile and execute the program

This generally happens when you are backpropagating and you attempt to exponentiate 1 which will give 0 somewhere inopportune. Where it happens in the data exactly is hard to predict depending on how random the distributions were during initiation or preactivation. There are some techniques which will pad the result of the exp() call that prevents 0 from happening. (1. / std::exp(x)) would heavily be my suspected site for this, and you could probably use 1 / (1 + exp(x)) to prevent it.

@TravisJ I tried but the problem still persists, thank you anyway.

I think your next step is "debugging" really. and maybe go over learncpp.com to get a bit more C++ knowledge before you continue.  E.g Basic file I/O

@PepijnKramer Yes, after this experience, i understood i need to study more. So could you give me some advice on how to "debug" in this situation. For now i tested every function in a simpliest case(less layers, weights and biases to check the calcutions) while writing the program, and they works. Now i'm trying to write a log file with the state of the network before and after every function call. There's something other that i can do, or something better? I really want to understand this problem to avoid it in the future. Thank you for your time.

I found the solution, in the sigmoide and sigmoide_derivative function there are exp() functions that for values to high of x returns a value too large, so instead they give NaN. I added a control that in case of NaN value returns 0. Probably in the debug mode this cases were automatically managed.
